# Как загрузить картинку в imageview с помощью intent-a?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Как загрузить картинку в imageview с помощью intent-a?

intent - камера и галерея.

Answer (score 2):

Для старта Intent-а используйте:

```
Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        activity.startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, code);
```

Где pickPhoto - Intent, code - константа.

Дальше:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`startactivityforresult`, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, `ACTION_PICK`